# error when rootScope updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular service that updates the `$rootScope`. The updating actually works fine, but it throws an error in the console which worries me.

```
app.service("scroll", function($rootScope, $window) {

  this.scrolling = function(delta){
    $rootScope.scroll.current -= delta;
  }

  $rootScope.$apply();

});
```

If I remove the `$rootScope.$apply()` the error doesn't appear, but then the rootScope value doesn't seem to be updated when I refer to it in my HTML.

For example in my HTML:

```
{{scroll.current}}
```

This only updates when I use `$rootScope.$apply()`. Is there a better way to update the `$rootScope`, or am I just doing something wrong?

Error being thrown:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.5/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Satpal I've updated my question with the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `$rootScope.$apply()` trigger a `$digest` and in angular at any point in time there can be only one `$digest` or `$apply` operation in progress.

Use `$timeout`.

```
app.service("scroll", function($rootScope, $window, $timeout) {
    this.scrolling = function(delta) {
        $rootScope.scroll.current -= delta;
    }

    $timeout(function() {
        $rootScope.$apply(); //this triggers a $digest
    }, 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your function:

```
$rootScope.$apply();
```

is called also when it is not needed.

You just have to add this line:

```
if ( !$rootScope.$$phase ) 
        $rootScope.$apply()
```

$$phase is when angular is digesting

**EDIT**: corrected $rootScope.apply() to $rootScope.$apply()

Comment: I wrote $rootScope.apply() instead of $rootScope.$apply()